# Meteor passing variable from template to iron router

Tags: templates, meteor

I'm wondering if it is possible to access variable / method of a template in iron:router.

My problem is : I want to reset a lot of stuff launched by my template (timer / subscription / whatever) on the page unload (from a change page menu)

But the window.onBeforeUnload is only triggered when we are changing the url. But my Iron:router is not reffreshing page and the only way i found to get this unload event is passing by iron:router's unload event. But there, I just can't access to my template variable or method. So the only way i found at the moment is passing my reset var by session... And i find this very awful !

```
Router.route('/printList', {
name: 'printjoblistList',
unload: function () {
   var reset = Session.get("sessionTestIronRouter");
}
```

Have you got advice, tips and bests ways to do that ? :)

Comment: I don't get when and what you're trying to do exactly but what you're searching for could be one of the following: onRendered, onCreated, onDestroyed

Comment: Thanks Luna for your answer, but I guess not. My event unload is well triggered when i'm changing page. The only thing I would like to do is accessing at my template's vars and methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved this, not very clean though.

I declared a globalHelper in my template client size :

```
Template.registerHelper('functionToCall', function () {
    // Code here
});
```

and in my unload iron's route :

```
Router.route('/template', {
    name: 'myTemplate',
    unload: function (e, obj) {
        Blaze._globalHelpers.functionToCall();
    }
});
```